# How to restart JBoss with maven-as plugin before redeploy

Tags: maven, jboss

I am having headaches trying to setup **maven-as-plugin**.

My goal is to redeploy an ear before running integration tests.
I want this process to be automatic to integrate it into CI.

The server is a JBoss server (AS 7) running remotely.

Thanks to infamous **PermGen** space issues of Jboss, I need to restart the server before 
deploying the ear. Otherwise, the server will explode every 5 runs or so ...

For that purpose, I have tried to setup a goal "**shutdown**", with reload=true.
The issue is that maven plugin won't wait for it to be finished before running the next goal (cleaning previous artifacts).

Here is an excerpt of my POM :

```
      <!-- Jboss Deploy/undeploy application EAR -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.jboss.as.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-as-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>7.5.Final</version>
        <configuration>

          <!-- JBoss management -->
          <hostname>${sanity.tests.jboss.host}</hostname>
          <port>${sanity.tests.management.port}</port>
          <username>${sanity.tests.jboss.username}</username>
          <password>${sanity.tests.management.password}</password>

        </configuration>

        <executions>

          <!-- Reload Jboss to avoid permgen space -->
          <execution>
            <id>restart</id>
            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
            <goals><goal>shutdown</goal></goals>
            <configuration>
              <reload>true</reload>
            </configuration>
          </execution> 

          <!-- Undeploy previous ear -->
          <execution>
            <id>undeploy</id>
            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
            <!-- Cleanup : Undeploy -->
            <goals>
              <goal>undeploy</goal>
            </goals>

            <configuration>
             <matchPattern>rm-app.*.ear</matchPattern>
              <ignoreMissingDeployment>true</ignoreMissingDeployment>
            </configuration>
          </execution>

          <!-- Deploy before int test --> 
          <execution>
            <id>deploy</id>
            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>deploy-artifact</goal>
            </goals>

            <configuration>
              <name>xxxx</name>
              <groupId>xxxxx</groupId>
              <artifactId>xxxx</artifactId>
              <version>${project.version}</version>
            </configuration> 

          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: It was so tedious and fragile than I switched to load my whole application into an embedded Jetty server.

Answer (score 0):

Try running your undeploy first. If that's the only ear on the AS then the reload will most likely be quick enough for the deploy goal to not timeout.

```
<goals>
    <goal>undeploy</goal>
    <goal>shutdown</goal>
    <goal>deploy</goal>
</goals>
```

Unfortunately, I do not know how to increase the timeout of the deploy goal.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue. switangs suggestion (first undeploy before restarting JBoss) for sure helps. Another thing i did to add some time between server restart and redeployment was to bind the undeploy and restart of the server to a very early step of the build process (e.g. initialize), whereas the deployment step was bind to process-resources or pre-integration-test as in your case. That worked because i was deploying my artifacts in a separate integration test module, which first copied all relevant server artifacts with maven-dependency-plugin plugin to the ${project.build.directory}/dependency folder as one of the first steps. 
But i agree that this is not a very good solution, a blocking restart cli command for standalone JBoss nodes would be much better.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, the shutdown goal won't solve the PermGen issue.
I worked this out by use cli.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jboss.as.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-as-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>7.5.Final</version>
    <configuration>
        <afterDeployment>
            <commands>
                <command>/host=master:shutdown(restart=true)</command>
            </commands>
        </afterDeployment>
    <!-- your configuration -->
    ...
    </configuration>
<plugin>
```

and "master" is the name of host in domain mode.